# Creating Model instance with a randomly generated, human sized, unique id

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I need a Model that has a field with a Random, Human-Sized, Unique key. We intend to use this for a human to brain-net the id to another computer and recall the data.

What I have:

```
def make_code():
    numbers = "".join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(4))
    letters = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(2))
    return numbers + letters

class PinRecord(models.Model):
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    data = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @classmethod
    def create_uniq(cls, action, data):
        created = False
        while not created:
            pin, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(pin=make_code(), defaults={'data':data})
        return pin.pin
```

Is there a better way to do create_uniq?

Right now, there is a small chance that it loops for a long time, especially if the PinRecords don't get cleaned up properly or traffic is higher then expected. An alternate version that limits attempts to a finite number leaves us with nothing to give the user except a middle finger error.

The recommended solution to the Random, Unique key problem seems to be uuid, but the users will object to writing down and retyping a uuid.

Comment: Are you creating a short lived one-time-pin?

Comment: Yes that is the intent. It should not live more then 5-10 minutes, and will be deleted once it is accepted.

Comment: In that case, try [pyotp](https://github.com/pyauth/pyotp) and you won't have to worry about entropy etc.